# HTML Textfield validation Backspace issue

Tags: javascript, html

I am validating the text field which should accept only characters it should not allow to enter numbers it is working good but when entering unwanted text the backspace is not working. I want to work it please give me advice.

This is my code:

```
function Validate_Classname() {
        var str = document.cclass.classname.value;
        if (IsBlank(str)) {
            alert("Class Name field cannot be empty")
            return false;
        }
        if (!isNaN(str)) {
            alert("Please enter only text")
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    function onlyAlphabets(e, t) {
        try {
            if (window.event) {
                var charCode = window.event.keyCode;
            }
            else if (e) {
                var charCode = e.which;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
            if ((charCode > 64 && charCode < 91)
                    || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        catch (err) {
            alert(err.Description);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backspace has a keyCode of 8.  Just return true when charCode == 8.

Your code should now be

```
    if ((charCode > 64 && charCode < 91)
                || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123) || (charCode == 8))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

instead of

```
    if ((charCode > 64 && charCode < 91)
                || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: where to specify charCode==8

Comment: I have included code sample in the answer.  Please look at it.